# change header style formattable R

Tags: html, r, formattable

I'm trying to use formattable with some values for species, thus, it's very important for column names to be italic; I've tried with the `formatter()` function, but it only acts on the values, even if I use the `"th"` node instead of `"span"`

```
library(formattable)
make_italic <- formatter("span",
                      style =  "font-style:italic")
formattable(mtcars, list(mpg = make_italic, qsec = make_italic))
```

In the mtcars, how may I change the names (mpg, cyl, disp,...) to italic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the `formattable` package, but the `make_italic` object that you create is a function that adds italics tags to character objects. You can use that on the column names directly. Because the names get changed you can no longer use them in your `formattable` function to format the columns, however you can format those column in the data.frame before changing the column names the same way. A bit hackish, but works.

```
library(formattable)
data(mtcars)
mtcars_tab        <- mtcars 
make_italic       <- formatter("span", style =  "font-style:italic")
mtcars_tab$mpg    <- make_italic(mtcars_tab$mpg)
mtcars_tab$qsec   <- make_italic(mtcars_tab$qsec)
names(mtcars_tab) <- make_italic(names(mtcars_tab))
formattable(mtcars_tab)
```

Comment: this workaround is quite cool, could this apply to some of the custom formatting options available in formattable as well? say color_tile, I did try `names(dt) <- color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0)`, but didn't work