# More style questions using formattable

Tags: r, formattable

In the table below, how do I remove the line between the Canada row and the World row?

Also, how do I remove the bold from the column headers (ie 1980, 2019, Change)?

This is different than the proposed link in that I wonder if there is a solution that is of the form:

```
# Define styles
row_emphasis <- formatter("span", style = ~style("font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "18px"))
make_non_bold <- formatter("span", style = "font-style:italic; font-weight:normal")


 # Apply styles
 formattable(can_world_table, list(
      area(row = 1) ~ row_emphasis,
      # column headers # ~ make_non_bold
      ))
```

---

As for the part about removing the lines between rows, the suggested answer below does not address my issue. This code adds another line between Canada and the header row line:

```
row_emphasis <- formatter("span", style = ~style("font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "18px", "border-top: 1px solid green"))
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)

target_year = 1980
current_year = 2019

can_target = 20.464
can2019 = 37.786

world_target = 6123
world2019 = 7456

can_change <- (can2019 - can_target) / can_target
world_change <- (world2019 - world_target) / world_target

can_world_table <- tibble(
  region = c("Canada", "World"),
  ty = c(round(can_target, digits = 0), round(world_target, digits = -2)),
  cy = c(can2019, round(world2019, digits = -2)),
  change = percent(c(can_change, world_change), 0)
) %>% 
  set_names(c("", target_year, current_year, "Change"))


can_world_table

can_world_table <- tibble(
  region = c("Canada", "World"),
  ty = c(can_target, format(round(world_target, digits = -2), big.mark = ",")),
  cy = c(can2019, format(round(world2019, digits = -2), big.mark = ",")),
  change = percent(c(can_change, world_change), 0)
) %>% 
  set_names(c(" ", target_year, current_year, "Change")) 

row_emphasis <- formatter("span", style = ~style("font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "18px"))
formattable(can_world_table, list(
  area(row = 1) ~ row_emphasis
  ))
```

Comment: ```make_non_bold <- formatter("span", style =  "font-style:italic; font-weight:normal")
names(can_world_table) <- make_non_bold(names(can_world_table))```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change header style formattable R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783329/change-header-style-formattable-r)

Comment: You can try using css or styles for `td` elements of your table which are set to `border-top: 1px solid #ddd;` overriding this stile with white colour can be an option